# Markdown to Word: How to convert text-only captions and crossferences to linked Word-ones?

Tags: vba, ms-word, r-markdown

The problem with knitting Markdown to Word is that the figure/table captions are text-only and hence do not change if a new figure/table is added to the document and are not shown in the list of figures/tables.

So how can you make real Word captions that are linked to their crossreferences and can be shown in the list of figures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the following VBA-script. There might be still ways to improve it, so I am happy about constructive comments.

The following converts figure captions like "Figure 3: Some Text" to "Figure 1.3: Some Text," hence includes the chapter numbers. If you want to exclude the chapter number, you cannot simply set `IncludeChapterNumber` to False because otherwise, the code cannot distinguish between the old and the new captions. One solution would be to set `IncludeChapterNumber`to False and change the new text to "Figure 1. Some Text." Hints to that are in the code.

To change the table captions, just replace "Figure" with "Table" and run the code again.

```
Sub Caption_Figure()
' This function converts simple text captions to real figure captions, which are correctly linked and can be displayed in the list of figures.
' Caution. The code will not work if there are too many spaces between "Figure" and its number!

    ' Make variables
        Dim originalCaption As String
        Dim LastCaption As String
        Dim IndexOfNewCaption As Integer
        Dim SearchFor As String
        Dim SearchIn As String
        Dim bfound As Boolean
        bfound = True
                
    ' Background settings of captions
        Call Caption_Figure_Background
            
    ' Start
    With Selection
        
        Do While bfound
        
            ' Search for caption
             With Selection.Find
                .Text = "Figure ([0-9]{1;8})(:)"  '1-8 digit numbers before a colon
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .ClearFormatting
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue  ' Don't ask per pop-up if search should be continued
                .Format = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                bfound = .Execute
            End With
                            
            If bfound Then
                
                ' Split original; insert caption
                    With Selection
                    
                        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                        ' Split original caption
                            Selection.Expand Unit:=wdParagraph
                            originalCaption = Selection.Text
                            originalCaption2 = Split(originalCaption, ":")  ' originalCaption2 consists of two parts: Figure/Figure # part and then the text after it
                            
                            
                        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                        ' Insert new caption
                            ' Write << Title:=". " & originalCaption2(1) >> to add a dot between the Figure number and the text
                        
                            .InsertCaption _
                                Label:=wdCaptionFigure, _
                                Title:=": " & originalCaption2(1), _
                                Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, _
                                ExcludeLabel:=0
                    End With
                

                                       
                ' Delete old caption
                     ' Caution! Simple Search and Replace does not work if the search text is more than one line long. Then it is not recognized and the caption is created twice!
                     ' Therefore only the first x characters are searched here. X should not be so long, so that also shorter captions can be found.
                     ' 10 is too small. 50 too large

                     With Selection.Find
                         .Text = Left(originalCaption, 25)  ' Search for the first x Characters
                         .Replacement.Text = ""
                         .Forward = True
                         .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                         .Format = False
                         .MatchCase = False
                         .MatchWholeWord = False
                         .MatchWildcards = False
                         .MatchSoundsLike = False
                         .MatchAllWordForms = False
                         cfound = .Execute
                     End With
                     
                     ' Delete whole paragraph with old caption
                        If cfound Then
                            With Selection
                                Selection.Expand Unit:=wdParagraph
                                Selection.Delete
                            End With
                        End If
                     
                ' Find index of new caption
                    AllCaptions = (ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(ReferenceType:="Figure"))
                    SearchFor = originalCaption2(1)
                    SearchFor = RemoveInvalidCharacters(SearchFor) ' originalCaption2(1))
                    SearchFor = Left(SearchFor, 40)
                    
                    For lngIndex = 1 To UBound(ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(ReferenceType:="Figure"))
                        SearchIn = AllCaptions(lngIndex)
                        SearchIn = RemoveInvalidCharacters(SearchIn)
                        If InStr(SearchIn, SearchFor) > 0 Then
                            IndexOfNewCaption = lngIndex
                        End If
                    Next lngIndex
                    
                    If IndexOfNewCaption = 0 Then
                        Debug.Print "Error: Index not found"
                    End If
                    
                ' Find references to figure-captions
                        With Selection.Find
                            .Text = originalCaption2(0) & "[) ,.;:^13]" & "[!0-9]"  ' Workaround because VBA doesn't do Lookaheads
                            .Replacement.Text = ""
                            .Forward = True
                            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                            .Format = False
                            .MatchWholeWord = False
                            .MatchCase = False
                            .MatchSoundsLike = False
                            .MatchWildcards = True
                            .MatchAllWordForms = False
                            .Execute
                        End With
                               
                        'If found: Insert crossreferences to the figure
                        Do While .Find.Found = True
                            LastCharacter = Right(Selection, 2) ' Workaround because VBA doesn't do Lookaheads
                        
                            With Selection
                                .InsertCrossReference _
                                    ReferenceType:="Figure", _
                                    ReferenceKind:=wdOnlyLabelAndNumber, _
                                    ReferenceItem:=IndexOfNewCaption, _
                                    InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
                                    IncludePosition:=False
                                .InsertAfter LastCharacter   ' Workaround because VBA doesn't do Lookaheads
                            End With
                            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                            .Find.Execute
                    
                        Loop
            End If

        Loop  ' bfound-Loop

    End With

End Sub

Function RemoveInvalidCharacters(cleanMe As String) As String
    ' Adjusted Code from https://gist.github.com/brazilnut2000/5972654

    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Pattern = "[\-\<\>\*\'\,\$\#\@\.\?\!\/\[\]\:\|\\\/\?|0-9]"
        .Global = True
        RemoveInvalidCharacters = .Replace(cleanMe, "")
    End With
End Function

Sub Caption_Figure_Background()
Debug.Print ("Do Caption_Figure_Background")

    With CaptionLabels("Figure")
        .NumberStyle = wdCaptionNumberStyleArabic
        .IncludeChapterNumber = True   ' Change to False if chapter numbers are not to be included. Caution: Also change new text!
        .ChapterStyleLevel = 1
        .Separator = wdSeparatorPeriod  ' = Value 1. Figure 1.1
    End With
            
End Sub
```

Remember: This code includes the chapter number. So if you don't have a Heading 1 in your document, you will get the error message "Error! No text of specified style in document"